# Get integer from inside parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string where I'm trying to grab the integer inside.  The string looks like:

> `"(2) This is a string"`

I need to grap that `2`.  but it could be any number so I tried:

```
 var str = "(2) this is a string";
 var patt = /\(\d\)/;

 var num = str.match(patt);
```

This doesn't return the correct answer.  Should I do a split on the `()` or is there a better regexp?

Comment: Is the number always going to be inside single parenthesis? Or could there be double parenthesis or the number be outside somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = "(2) this is a string";
var patt = /\((\d)\)/;

var num = str.match(patt)[1];
```

2 things. When you want to capture a segment form a matched string, you use `()` to note that. So I just wrapped the `\d` in parens to capture it.

Second, in order to access the captured segments, you must drill into the returned array. the `match` method will return an array where the first item is the entire matched string, and the second item is any matched capture groups. So use `[1]` to fetch the first capture group (second item in array)

Comment: will that work with more than one digit?  It might be 1 it might be 100.

Comment: `(\d)` matches and captures a single digit. but `(\d+)` will match one or more digits. The `+` says one or more the previous token.

Comment: one more thing...is there a way to do what you answered above and get something like (0.5)?  Or is that a different kind of animal?

Comment: It's a little trickier. Don't think of it as a `0.5` as a decimal number. Think of it as a string. So some digits and optionally a dot with more digits. `(\d+(\.\d+)?)`. So internally in the capture group, we defined an optional sub expression. The `?` says 0 or 1 of those. So `23` is matched and `23.45`, but not `23.`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "(2) this is a string";
var patt = /\((\d+)\)/;
alert(str.match(patt)[1]);
```

This works!

*Why it works.* Because inside the (()) mayhem there's also a capture which populates the [1] elements in the matches array.

Comment: Nope... only if you have the expression inside a string.

Comment: @FelixKling in Javascript, RegEx expressions can take on the above syntax. The above code is correct and will work as expected in JavaScript, which this question is tagged as.

Comment: @SeanJohnson I edited the response. It was broken first time :)

Comment: will this return more than one digit?  For example 10 instead of 2?

Comment: @Verber Now it does. Added an extra +.

Answer (score 0):

Use this. doesnt matter how many parenthesis

```
var str = "(2) this is a string";
var patt = /\(\d\)/;

var num = str.match(patt)[0].replace("(", "").replace(")","")
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

```
 var str = "(2) this is a string";
var a =  /\([\d]*\)/g.exec(str)[0];
 var num =  a.substring(1, a.length-1);
```